SQLAlchemy: Error can't emit change event
So, I have these 2 dto classes:
class ProjectDTO(DB):
    __tablename__ = 'projects'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'postgres'}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    serial = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), unique=True, nullable=False, server_default=text('(uuid_generate_v4())'))
    team_engineer_serial = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('postgres.team.serial'))
    team_tester_serial = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('postgres.team.serial'))

    statuses = relationship('ProjectStatusDTO', back_populates='project', foreign_keys='[ProjectStatusDTO.project_serial]')
    team_engineer = relationship('TeamDTO', backref='project_as_engineer', foreign_keys=[team_engineer_serial])
    team_tester = relationship('TeamDTO', backref='project_as_tester', foreign_keys=[team_tester_serial])

class ProjectStatusDTO(DB):
    __tablename__ = 'project_statuses'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'postgres'}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    serial = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), unique=True, nullable=False, server_default=text('(uuid_generate_v4())'))
    project_serial = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('postgres.projects.serial'))
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    is_initial = Column(Boolean)

    project = relationship('ProjectDTO', back_populates='statuses', foreign_keys=[project_serial])

Then, I have a function to get the project details, including the list of statuses, using function below.
    def _get_project(self, ctx: Context, project_code: str = None, team_engineer_serial: str = None, with_initial_status: bool = False):
        if not project_code and not team_engineer_serial:
            raise BadRequestError("one of 'project_code' or 'team_engineer_serial' must be provided")

        query = ctx.get_db_catalog().query(ProjectDTO)

        if project_code:
            query = query.filter(ProjectDTO.code == project_code)
        else:
            query = query.filter(ProjectDTO.team_engineer_serial == team_engineer_serial)

        if with_initial_status:
            query = query.join(ProjectDTO.statuses).filter(ProjectStatusDTO.is_initial == True)

        query = query.options(
            joinedload(ProjectDTO.statuses),
            joinedload(ProjectDTO.team_engineer)
        )

        result = query.first()

        if not result:
            return None

        return ProjectEntity().from_dto(result)

Unfortunately, the function above produce error raise orm_exc.ObjectDereferencedError( sqlalchemy.orm.exc.ObjectDereferencedError: Can't emit change event for attribute 'ProjectDTO.statuses' - parent object of type <ProjectDTO> has been garbage collected.
What's wrong with my function?
Thank you.

Can you provide a little bit more context to your code? What are Context and  ProjectEntity classes, for example? If they are not involved in your problem, can you provide a [example] instead?
